# Merge sort and linked list implementation

Tags: java, performance, linked-list, mergesort

I implemented merge sort with my own linked list for a school project. I was not allowed to use anything but the methods you see in the list. It seems to work properly, however, when running the provided testbed, I am told that the implementation is likely \$O(n^2)\$.

I've looked for a long time trying to find where my implementation is \$O(n^2)\$ but have had no luck. I would appreciate:

- any input on the quality of the implementation
- any information on why the implementation is so inefficient

---

```
public class Sort {

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(IUListWithListIterator<T> list) {
            _sort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
        }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void _sort(IUListWithListIterator<T> list, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            _sort(list, low, middle);
            _sort(list, middle + 1, high);
            merge(list, low, middle, high);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(IUListWithListIterator<T> list, int low, int middle, int high) {
        IUListWithListIterator<T> temp = new IUDoubleLinkedList<T>();

        ListIterator<T> left = list.listIterator(middle);
        ListIterator<T> right = list.listIterator(high);

        while (left.previousIndex() + 1 >= low && right.previousIndex() + 1 > middle) {
            T l = left.previous();
            T r = right.previous();
            if (l.compareTo(r) > 0) {
                temp.addToFront(l);
                right.next();
            }
            else {
                temp.addToFront(r);
                left.next();
            }
        }

        while (left.previousIndex() + 1 >= low) {
            temp.addToFront(left.previous());
        }
        while (right.previousIndex() + 1 > middle) {
            temp.addToFront(right.previous());
        }

        ListIterator<T> tempIter = temp.listIterator();
        left.next();
        while(tempIter.hasNext()) {
            left.set(tempIter.next());
            left.next();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class IUDoubleLinkedList<T> implements IndexedUnorderedList<T>, IUListWithListIterator<T> {


private Node head;
private Node tail;
private int size;


public IUDoubleLinkedList() {
    head = new Node(null, null, null);
    tail = new Node(null, head, null);
    head.setNext(tail);
    size = 0;
}

public T removeFirst() {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Empty list");
    }
    Node first = head.getNext();
    removeNode(first);
    return first.getData();
}

public T removeLast() {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Empty list");
    }
    Node last = tail.getPrev();
    removeNode(last);
    return last.getData();
}

public T remove(T element) {
    Node target = findNode(element);
    if (target == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Element " + element + " not in list");
    }
    removeNode(target);
    return target.getData();
}

public T first() {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Empty list");
    }
    return head.getNext().getData();
}

public T last() {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Empty list");
    }
    return tail.getPrev().getData();
}

public boolean contains(T target) {
    Node found = findNode(target);
    return found == null ? false : true;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    if (size == 0) {
        b.append("[]");
    }
    else {
        b.append("[");
        Node currentNode = head.getNext();
        while (currentNode != tail) {
            b.append(currentNode.getData().toString() + ", ");
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        if (b.length() > 3) {
            b = new StringBuilder(b.substring(0, b.length() - 2));
        }
        b.append("]");
    }
    return b.toString();
}

public void addToFront(T element) {
    addNode(new Node(element), head, head.getNext());       
}

public void addToRear(T element) {
    addNode(new Node(element), tail.getPrev(), tail);       
}

public void addAfter(T element, T target) {
    Node targetNode = findNode(target);
    if (targetNode == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Element " + target + " not in list");
    }
    addNode(new Node(element), targetNode, targetNode.getNext());   
}

public void add(int index, T element) {
    if (index > size || index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " is out of bounds");
    }
    else if (index == 0) {
        addToFront(element);
        return;
    }
    else if (index == size) {
        addToRear(element);
    }

    else {
        Node targetNode = findNode(index);
        addNode(new Node(element), targetNode.getPrev(), targetNode);
    }
}

public void set(int index, T element) {
    if (index >= size || index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " is out of bounds");
    }
    Node setNode = findNode(index);
    Node newNode = new Node(element, setNode.getPrev(), setNode.getNext());
    setNode.getPrev().setNext(newNode);
    setNode.getNext().setPrev(newNode);
}

public void add(T element) {
    addNode(new Node(element), tail.getPrev(), tail);       
}

public T get(int index) {
    if (index >= size || index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " is out of bounds");
    }
    Node target = findNode(index);
    return target.getData();
}

public int indexOf(T element) {
    int i = 0;
    Node currentNode = head.getNext();
    while (currentNode != tail) {
        if (currentNode.getData().equals(element)) {
            return i;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

public T remove(int index) {
    if (index > size - 1 || index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " is out of bounds");
    }
    Node targetNode = findNode(index);
    removeNode(targetNode);
    return targetNode.getData();
}

public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new DLLIterator();
}


private class DLLIterator implements Iterator<T> {

    private Node next;

    private DLLIterator() {
        next = head.getNext();
    }

    private DLLIterator(int index) {
        next = findNode(index);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != tail;
    }

    public T next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        next = next.getNext();
        return next.getPrev().getData();
    }

    public void remove() {
        removeNode(next.getPrev());
    }

}

public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
    return new DLLListIterator<T>();
}

public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int startingIndex) {
    return new DLLListIterator<T>(startingIndex);
}

private class DLLListIterator<E> implements ListIterator<T> {

    Node current;
    Node last;
    int index;

    private DLLListIterator() {
        current = head.getNext();
        last = null;
        index = 0;
    }

    private DLLListIterator(int startingIndex) {
        current = findNode(startingIndex);
        index = startingIndex;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != tail;
    }

    public T next() {
        if (current.getNext() == last) {
            current = last.getNext();
            index++;
            return last.getData();
        }
        last = current;
        current = current.getNext();
        index++;
        return last.getData();
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (last == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("can't call remove() before calling next() or previous()");
        }
        removeNode(last);
        last = null;
        index--;
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return current != head;
    }

    public T previous() {
        if (last != null && last.getNext() == current) {
            current = last.getPrev();
            index--;
            return last.getData();
        }
        last = current;
        current = current.getPrev();
        index--;
        return last.getData();
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        if (last == null) {
            addNode(new Node(element), current.getPrev(), current);
        }
        else if (last.getNext() == current) {
            addNode(new Node(element), last, current);
        }
        else if (current.getNext() == last) {
            addNode(new Node(element), current, last);
        }

        index++;
    }

    public void set(T element) {
        if (last == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("can't call set(T) before calling next() or previous()");
        }
        last.setData(element);
    }

    public int nextIndex() {
        return index + 1;
    }

    public int previousIndex() {
        return index - 1;
    }

}


private class Node {

    private Node prev;
    private Node next;
    private T data;

    public Node(T data, Node before, Node after) {
        this.prev = before;
        this.next = after;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }
    public void setPrev(Node n) {
        prev = n;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(T d) {
        data = d;
    }
}

private void addNode(Node n, Node before, Node after) {
    before.setNext(n);
    after.setPrev(n);
    n.setNext(after);
    n.setPrev(before);
    size++;
}

private void removeNode(Node n) {
    if (n == head) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't remove the head of the list");
    }
    if (n == tail) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't remove the tail of the list");
    }
    n.getPrev().setNext(n.getNext());
    n.getNext().setPrev(n.getPrev());
    size--;
}

private Node findNode(T target) {
    Node currentNode = head.getNext();
    while (currentNode != tail) {
        if (currentNode.getData() == target) {
            return currentNode;
        }
        //System.out.println(currentNode.getData());
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
    return null;
}

private Node findNode(int index) {
    if (index > size || index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (index == size) {
        return tail;
    }
    Node currentNode = head.getNext();
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
    return currentNode;
}

}
```

Comment: You are taking an index-based approach to a problem in which there is no use of index at all. In `_sort(..)`, you call `list.listIterator(index)` every time and it in turn calls `findNode(..)` which is O(n). This dramatically inscreases your runtime. I don't see any other reason for the O(n^2) runtime. Take a look at the [classical merge sort for linkedlists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation_using_lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking an index-based approach to a problem in which there is no use of index at all. In `_sort(..)`, you call `list.listIterator(index)` every time and it in turn calls `findNode(..)` which is \$O(n)\$. This dramatically increases your runtime. I don't see any other reason for the overall \$O(n^2)\$ runtime. Take a look at the [classical merge sort for linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation_using_lists).